# How to use getnodelist?

Tags: pstricks, pst-node

Taken from `pst-node`'s documentation on page 39:

This very short description about `\getnodelist` does not help me (maybe others as well) understand how to use it.

[image]

Could you give me an example how to use `\getnodelist` with non-empty `<next command>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging from the source of `pst-node.tex`, there is not a difference between

```
\getnodelist{<name>}{\command}(…)(…)…
```

and

```
\getnodelist{<name>}{}(…)(…)… \command
```

Even in the latter example you can use `\PST@root`(= `<name>`) and `\pst@args` (holds the number of the latest `<name>` node) without a problem.

The first version forces a more systematic structure (e.g. `\command` explicitly uses the following  nodes). Using it elsewhere might produce unexpected results.

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks,multido,pst-node}
\makeatletter
\def\myCircles#1{%
    \multido{\iCount=0+1}{\the\numexpr\pst@args+1\relax}{
        \pscircle*(\PST@root\iCount){#1}
    }
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
    \begin{pspicture}(7,7)
    \getnodelist{P}{\myCircles{.25}}(2,2)(2,5)(5,2)(5,5)
    \end{pspicture}
    \begin{pspicture}(7,7)
    \getnodelist{P}{}(2,2)(2,5)(5,2)(5,5)\myCircles{.25}
    \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

There is no difference. They produce exactly the same result.

But if you want to provide an own macro, say `\pstDottedNodes`, you as the author of this `\pstDottedNodes` macro wouldn’t have a chance to prepend `\myCircles`. (It becomes even clearer when you want to hide the internal `<name>`s from the user and `\pstDottedNodes` only has one parameter (the radius).)

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks,multido,pst-node}
\makeatletter
\def\pstDottedNodes#1#2{\getnodelist{#1}{\myCircles{#2}}}
\def\myCircles#1{%
    \multido{\iCount=0+1}{\the\numexpr\pst@args+1\relax}{
        \pscircle*(\PST@root\iCount){#1}
    }
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(7,7)
\pstDottedNodes{P}{.25}(2,2)(2,5)(5,2)(5,5)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: use the node name instead of `\PST@root`

Comment: @Herbert: Why did you use `PST` rather than `pst` for the root node name?

Answer (score 4):

Here is a quick example showing that answers the question that illustrates how to draw a (closed) polygon from a sequence of points:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multido,pst-node}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{multido,pst-node}
\makeatletter
\newcounter{mycount}
\newcommand{\drawpolygon}{%
  \setcounter{mycount}{\csname\PST@root nodecount\endcsname}% Extract number of nodes
    \stepcounter{mycount}\pnode(\PST@root 0){\PST@root\themycount}% Add extra node that matches origin node (for closed polygon)
  \multido{\iA=0+1,\iB=1+1}{\value{mycount}}{%
      \psline(\PST@root\iA)(\PST@root\iB)\psdot(\PST@root\iA)}% Draw line + dot
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}
    \SpecialCoor
    \getnodelist{P}{\drawpolygon}(1,1)(2,1)(2,2)(1,2)
    \degrees[5]
    \rput{0}(4,2){\getnodelist{Q}{\drawpolygon}(1;0)(1;1)(1;2)(1;3)(1;4)}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

The idea is to use `\getnodelist` to call `\drawpolygon` *after* specifying a bunch of nodes. Each node has a root name (first argument to `\getnodelist`), stored in `\PST@root`.

Answer (score 4):

Werners solution with some modifications:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multido,pst-node}

\newcommand\drawpolygon[1]{{%
  \psset{showpoints}
  \multido{\iA=0+1}{\csname#1nodecount\endcsname}{%
    \psline(#1\iA)(#1\the\numexpr\iA+1)}
  \psline(#1 0)(#1\csname#1nodecount\endcsname)}}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}
    \getnodelist{P}{\drawpolygon{P}}(1,1)(2,1)(2,2)(1,2)
    \degrees[5]
    \rput{0}(4,2){\getnodelist{Q}{\drawpolygon{Q}}(1;0)(1;1)(1;2)(1;3)(1;4)}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Passing `P` to `\drawpolygon` in `\getnodelist{P}{\drawpolygon{P}}(1,1)(2,1)(2,2)(1,2)` should not be necessary because (1) it can be inferred internally, (2) it increases the potential of error prone (users accidentally pass a different name).

Comment: nice that you want to tell me how my own code works internally ...

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{multido,pst-node}
\makeatletter

\newcommand\psPolygon[2][my@pst@node@name]{\getnodelist{#1}{\my@Polygon{#2}}}

\def\my@Polygon#1{%
    \pscustom[#1]
    {
        \psnline{-}(0,\csname\PST@root nodecount\endcsname){\PST@root}
        \closepath
    }
    \multido{\i=0+1}{\the\numexpr\pst@args+1\relax}{%
        \pscircle*(\PST@root\i){2pt}
    }\ignorespaces
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(5,5)
\psPolygon{fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=orange,origin={2.5,2.5}}(0,0)(5,0)(5,5)(0,5)
\end{pspicture}

\qquad

\begin{pspicture}(-2,-2)(2,2)
\degrees[5]
\psPolygon[Karl]{fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=orange}(1;0)(1;1)(1;2)(1;3)(1;4)
\psline(Karl0)(Karl2)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```